# FTP external connection on pureftp server - fails to retrieve directory

Tags: linux, ftp, pure-ftpd

the context is I have a Chinese ipcamera which needs to send security footage on a remote ftp server.

I have configured a pure-ftpd server which works correctly on LAN. I have defined a PassivePortRange and set ufw rules and opened the corresponding ports on my router.
The problem is when I try connecting from outside the local network.

```
Status: Connecting to x.x.x.x:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Plain FTP is insecure. Please switch to FTP over TLS.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "****" is your current location
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (x,x,x,x,191,155)
Command:    MLSD
Response:   150 Accepted data connection
Response:   226 21 matches total
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

The ports are confirmed accessible from outside (using port checker tool). I noticed when checking open ports that pureftp binds to local address

```
tcp        0      0 192.168.x.x:      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      124031/pure-ftpd (U 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      123798/pure-ftpd (S 
tcp        0      0 192.168.x.x:      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      122365/pure-ftpd (I
```

I am not sure if this is the source of my problem. I have also tried setting ForcePassiveIP, but with absolutely no change in remote connection behaviour.
I am aware that my problem is somewhere in my configuration, however after several hours of troubleshooting, I can't seem to find the root cause.

Comment: *"The ports are confirmed accessible from outside"* – What ports did you check? + Does the `x,x,x,x,x` in `227 ...` match the `x.x.x.x` in `Connecting to ...`?

Comment: I specifically checked the ports pureftpd was listening on during the connection (the ones from the range set in PassivePortRange). Yes, the IP address in 227 matches.

Comment: Does the range include 49051?

Comment: Yes. It's in the range set in PassivePortRange and also the port is opened in my router's configuration.

Comment: Well, *something* blocks or does not route it.